# Can I work on resetting pavers on my patio after a heavy rain?

Tags: patio

This is about a pavers patio. If you are curious about the whole context please see my other questions.

Last night it rained a lot. I have some problems due to water collecting near the wall of my house from the patio. I am planning to reset the stones in some areas and to install a french drain between my house and the patio.

Is it OK to work on the above after such a heavy rain? There is more rain to come and I want to stop this madness with the water pooling near the wall when it rains heavily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this should not be a problem. Under your patio should be various layers of gravel that should drain the water well. If the rain unsettles anything, you can always tamp it out while doing your repairs, but I would not expect much damage.